# tif image does not display in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Well, I have some `tif` images and I want to write a program using Python to display a window using Tkinter with a combo box and a frame then choose one of the images and display it in the frame, but when I try to do this, it shows me just a white frame.

When I'm trying with other image formats like `PNG` it works well, but with tif images it does not work.

These `TIF` images are from `Landsat-9` and this is one of my projects from Remote Sensing Class.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import customtkinter as ctk
import PIL 

Image_Names = sorted(os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Shahriar\Documents\WorkSpace\RS\Landsat-9"), key=len)

ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

Window = ctk.CTk()
Window.title("RS")
Window.iconbitmap("./Satellite.ico")
Window.geometry("1280x720")

Frame = ctk.CTkFrame(Window, width=820, height=820)

def clear_frame():
        for widgets in Frame.winfo_children():
                widgets.destroy()

def OpenImage(choice):
        clear_frame()
        global image
        image = PIL.Image.open(f"./Landsat-9/{choice}")
        final_Image = ctk.CTkImage(dark_image=image, size=(800, 800))
        Label = ctk.CTkLabel(Frame, text="", image=final_Image)
        Label.configure(image = final_Image)
        Label.pack(pady=10)
        return

Combo_Img = ctk.CTkComboBox(Window, values=Image_Names, command=OpenImage)
Combo_Img.pack(pady=10)
Frame.pack(pady=10, expand=True)

Window.mainloop()
```

Comment: PIL wants `.tiff` not `.tif`, rename it.

Comment: it does not work Ethier.

Comment: Sorry, I got that info from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267989/opening-tiff-image-in-pil-python)

Comment: Can you provide sample file for testing? As I cannot reproduce the issue with a sample GeoTiff file downloaded from internet. Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0QgU.png)

Comment: it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0) pollute the namespace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091

Comment: @BryanOakley It is not a duplicate of that question because `CTkLabel` will keep a reference of the image. Also OP said other image types can be seen.